# Migration to Spring Boot is causing problems with Spring Batch

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I'm trying to convert an older application that so far only uses Spring to Spring Boot. I managed to get the application to run again. But I'm having problems with Spring Batch.

The application uses Spring + Spring Batch + Spring Security + Hibernate + Wicket + ojdbc and is running on Tomcat with a Oracle 19c database.

I'm fighting these Spring Batch problems:

1. Massive performance drop: A Batch Step that took 2 minutes before is now running for an hour. This seems to me like it's caused by a slow database connection. Spring Batch spends a lot of time creating the objects with the ItemReader.
2. The Spring Job fails at the end with a "ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update" There is a versioned table that contains the status of the calculations. This status is updated multiple times during the Batch Job. The status update works in the beginning, but near the end the EntityManager returns an result with an outdated version. Updating causes the exception.

Do you have any ideas or hints what could cause these problems? The functionality was not changed, this should only be a migration to Spring Boot.

Comment: Please specify the current/next versions of spring batch and spring boot. For 1), we need a sample to check what could be causing this performance hit. For 2) Was this happening before or it happens only after the migration? Same here, we would need a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that reproduces the issue to be able to help you in an efficient way.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.